# image src (url) not working

Tags: php, html

I have image tag like below

```
<img src="www.example.com/imgs/file.jpg" />
```

but this is not working and when i look at page src i see

```
<img  src="site1/std/www.example.com/imgs/file.jpg" />
```

i tried to escape the two dirs by adding

```
<img  src="../../www.example.com/imgs/file.jpg" />
```

but this just give me :

```
<img  src="../../site1/std/www.example.com/imgs/file.jpg" />
```

what's wrong with my code???

Comment: you need to add `http://` here or a relative path.

Comment: `<a>` elements use `href`, not `src`.

Comment: also not working

Comment: I love this *"not working"*. There's not enough information to support the question and how is this php related?

Comment: sorry its img not a

Comment: coz i changed the way i process this like so:
$img = ' <img src="www.example.com/imgs-files/file.jpg" /> ';

and pass this var to html whih read it like this

std_image: {img}

alson when i look at img tag it seems to have extra special chars on it

<img src="www.example.com/imgs(somespectialchars)files/file.jpg" />

Comment: How would the browser know that "www..." is supposed to be a domain name? How's it different from `src="foo/bar/"`? It's not. If you want to refer to a domain, you need the full URL starting with `http://`.

Comment: I don't see this question adding any value to the network questions/answers base, IMHO.

Comment: You went and changed your post and not marking it as an edit, or mentioned what you tried from the answer below or commented under the answer (edit: oh, so now you comment). I rolled the question back to a previous revision. c.c.: @deceze

Answer (score 3):

If the image is located on the server where your script is, then you can use

```
<img src="imgs/file.jpg" />
```

If its on an external site, then you need to use the full link, like so

```
<img src="http://www.example.com/imgs/file.jpg" />
```

Comment: right; which was said in comments but they failed to test that

Comment: it's on external site but it gives me like so

<img  src="../../site1/std/http://www.example.com/imgs/file.jpg" />

Comment: you need to get the full link to the image, so that that image link can be put in a browser and will then result in the image. So http:// is needed in front